# Identifying Aggregates and Aggregate roots for an application

Tags: transactions, domain-driven-design, database-schema, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have been reading about DDD, Event Sourcing (ES) and CQRS. I realized that if we consider ES and CQRS, aggregates have been at the central of the design.
Please correct me if I am wrong but I learned that:

1. Each command will correspond to one aggregate, this could help us in defining the commands
2. Each event streams corresponds to one aggregate, making it easy for us to define the events structure.

Now I was just thinking that if possible is there any tool or method that can help us in identifying the aggregates in the already existing application from some inputs?
I believe that "Historical transaction logs" and "Database Schema" as inputs can be really be helpful for getting some knowledge about some structure of the aggregates. I may be wrong here again, but has anyone tried something on the similar line to make the process of finding aggregates easy for the software engineers?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about getting historical transaction logs and DB schemas from some existing system (presumably the one which you're looking to replace with a system designed following Domain Driven Design), I would strongly caution against that approach.

For the existing implementation, the transaction logs and schemas are at best an encoding of the domain and likely have discarded some context and contorted the domain in some way to fit the constraints of the DB.  If those are your main basis for discovering the domain, your likely best case is that you end up with a clone of the existing system that's inferior in some way.

The easiest way to find the aggregates is to look at what operations are desired and tracing how those operations' sequencing affects each other (e.g. "how does this command succeeding affect whether this later command succeeds"; if the answer is "no effect" then those commands are almost certainly not to the same aggregate, since in CQRS-style DDD the purpose of the aggregate is to determine whether commands succeed or fail).  This is typically going to entail working with domain experts to explore the domain, e.g. via event storming (or some similar technique).

Comment: Thanks.
I understand. My approach is to help the developer first identify the aggregates based on the existing information about the application which is not DDD based. If transaction logs and DB schema are not enough, as per your explanation, I am open to include other available information to give user an idea about the aggregates boundaries in the application. I am not considering it to be 100% perfect, but close to it. My main idea is to try to avoid techniques like event storming, or other similar technique, and still come up with some boundary level of aggregates in the system.

Comment: Since aggregates define transaction boundaries, about the best you could do (assuming every kind of desired transaction occurs in the log) is for each column in each table, take the other table/columns that were updated in the same transaction.  Then possible aggregates can be derived from the "transitive closure" (if A is updated (even once) with B and B is updated at least once alongside C than A, B, and C are in the same aggregate).  Maybe you'll get lucky and get usable aggregates out of that, but it's just as likely that you'll end up with one aggregate to rule the world...

Comment: ...that aggregate being, basically, a terrible database that can only process one transaction at a time.  Moving beyond this requires domain knowledge.

Comment: Thanks a lot Levi. This is actually what I had in mind too. I understand that there might be cases where I will end up with only one aggregate. To avoid such cases I was looking more into "How to define the relationships between the entities" which are identified in the same aggregate. The relationship could be anything which will say that those two entities should belong to same aggregate and it is ok to leave out the entity which is identified to be in the same aggregate because their relationship is not strong. I want that metric which would measure their relationship.

Comment: I know that result could be very terrible aggregate, and its a long shot, but I have to come up with something regarding this...

Comment: There's no metric derivable solely from the DB which will help you, because it depends on the importance to the business of consistency between a given pair of transactions and that, at minimum, requires asking questions.